# C# Lambda and LINQ tutorial for an experienced functional programmer

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

I would like to learn the "functional" parts of C# (.NET 4). As a long time Haskell and Lisp programmer, I would prefer not to get distracted by explanations of basic concepts. Is there a book/tutorial that I should check out?

Comment: How well do you know C#?

Comment: If you just want to go to some code, check out Microsoft's 101 LINQ Samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx

Comment: This question is better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Erno: Well enough to write web applications and scrapers and not get fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out 101 Examples on Linq [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: Most helpful website I have found for LINQ hands down.

Comment: I used if when i was learning and it was really helpful!

Comment: link is down...

Comment: updated one --> https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the link

Answer (score 3):

Just look at the [docs for the methods in `System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx).

These methods are standard functional programming operations with slightly different names (`Select` == `Map`, `Where` == `Filter`, `Aggregate` = `foldl`, etc)

You'll also need to understand [iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx); see Jon Skeet's [excellent in-depth article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx).

You should already understand lambda expressions and closures.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to learn the "functional" parts of C# (.NET 4). As a long time Haskell and Lisp programmer, I would prefer not to get distracted by explanations of basic concepts. Is there a book/tutorial that I should check out?

Yes, there is a book made just for you! Check out [Real-World Functional Programming With Examples in F# and C#](http://www.manning.com/petricek/). Extraordinarily good book.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading some of Bart De Smet's blog posts for a decent view of the more theoretical side of C# lambdas and how they interact with LINQ.  He doesn't blog often but he's got a good list of some of the more interesting posts [here](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2010/01/03/top-9-posts-from-2009.aspx).  I particularly like his post on [MinLINQ](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2010/01/01/the-essence-of-linq-minlinq.aspx).

If you wanted to jump in I'd say look at one of the many tutorials using parser combinators in C# and build your own library (with Haskell experience I'm sure you'll find it pretty easy). [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2007/08/19/monadic-parser-combinators-using-c-3-0.aspx) is one of the more popular tutorials but a quick search reveals plenty more.

Comment: I wish he'd start posting again. His blog is so good.

Comment: Agreed. I think he did a Channel9 video not terribly long ago though.